# How to give multiple bitmaps as inputs in gpuimage?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

I am pretty beginner in OpenGL in android. I am using GPUImage Android for applying filters on images. But, my fragment shader requires three input bitmaps to produce the output.

```c
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3;
uniform float intensity;
```

But as far as I know GPUImage supports `GPUImageTwoInputFilter`. So, what program should I write for giving three bitmaps to the same shader. Or there is any simple way I can use OpenGL for this task.

Comment: Even to use GPUImageTwoInputFilter is not clear; Could you please tell how do I use shaders with two bitmaps; Like I want to apply blending effect? Simple filter effect is working but don't know how to set two textures to get a exact result?

Comment: Well two input filter is pretty easy to use. These filters are mostly Blend filters
GPUImageLightenBlendFilter blend = new GPUImageLightenBlendFilter(0.5f);
blend.setBitmap(bitmap); // The bitmap which is used as blending 

GPUImage gpu = new GPUImage(this);
gpu.setFilter(blend);
gpu.setBitmap(bitmap1); // The bitmap to apply blending to
Bitmap output  = gpu.getBitmapWithFilterApplied();